# Object propagation

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5

I have a collection of objects, lets say `QVector<ApplicationStates>`, which registers the most important operations done in my software. Basically, this object is meant to process redo/undo operations.The application is built using a lot of delegated objects. Operations which have to be registered lie in a lot of these objects. As such, I am always passing  my collection of objects, in each delegate under the form:

```
class AWidget : public QWidget{
    AWidget(QVector<ApplicationStates>* states, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ...
```

It seems ugly to me. I think about two solutions:

- Singleton;
- Simply declare the `QVector` as a static global variable (I read that global variables are evil).

Does someone have a suggestion?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: How many instances of `QVector<ApplicationStates` are there?    If there is just one, and you are passing it everywhere by reference, consider using a singleton.     I wouldn't just use a static global, since that prevents things like reentrancy of your code and makes it harder to work with using multiple threads.   If there are multiple instances, then it is probably better to pass instances as arguments to functions that need it (by reference rather than pointer though).

Comment: @peter  There is just one instance

Comment: Singletons have most of the same problems as globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get into a similar situation from time to time, and I have found simply wrapping your vector in a class called something like "ApplicationContext" then passing a shared pointer or reference to an instance of that around saves the day. It has many benefits:

- You avoid the global / singleton, and you are free to in fact have several instances concurrently in the future
- If you suddenly have more than just that vector of objects that you need to pass arround, simply extend your context class to add whatever you need
- If your vector suddenly becomes a map or changes in other ways, you need not change any interfaces that pass it along such as the signals/slots. (You will need to change the implementation where the vector is used of course).
- BONUS: The code becomes easily testable! You can now make test cases for this class.

This might not be the best solution in all cases, but I think it comes pretty close in this case!